# How to load multiple, dependent Backbone models?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, javascript-framework

My Backbone app includes Views which depend on multiple models.  For example, I define 2 models:

```
var user = new UserModel({id:1});
user.fetch();
var place = new PlaceModel({id:1});
place.fetch();
```

Now I want to render a View that depends on both these models:

```
var home = new House({owner: user, address: place});
home.render()
```

I don't want to render the View until I'm sure all the models have loaded.
What is the right way to make sure that `user` and `place` have both been fetched before I render `home`?

I'm currently using a sequential process:

```
user.bind("change", function() {place.fetch();});
place.bind("change", function() {home.render();});
user.fetch();
```

But this gets unwieldy as the dependencies grow and I feel like there must be a better way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backbone `fetch` uses jQuery for AJAX calls, and like a plain `$.ajax` call, returns a [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.

This means that waiting for multiple calls to finish can be done quite elegantly using  `$.when`:

```
var place = new PlaceModel({id:96});
var user = new UserModel({id:2458});
var home = new House({owner: user, address: place});

//both .fetch() calls return a promise
//when waits for promises to be fulfilled (or rejected)
$.when(place.fetch(), user.fetch())
  .done(home.render);
  .fail(showError);
```

*Edit: Earlier version of this answer claimed that Backbone.localStorage does not return a deferred, but it does, so this solution also works with that plugin.*

Comment: nice! I had been reading about jQuery's deferred but your example makes it clear that this is the way to go. Is RequireJS something I need to be thinking about here... or is that just for the initial loading of my JS assets?

Comment: @lubar, require.js is not related to usage of deferred - but since you asked, if your codebase is large, I recommend it in general. I also recommend using deferreds, since they can simplify the callback jungle that is javascript. See http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/12/jquerydeferred-is-most-important-client.html for a great introduction to using the jQuery Deferred.